# Login member programmatically on Umbraco 7

Tags: authentication, umbraco, umbraco7

I am battling with this. In Umbraco 6 you could easily do this using:

```
Member.AddMemberToCache(
    Member.GetMemberFromEmail(email),
    true,
    new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
);
```

I don't to find the same thing in the umbraco 7 member's service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Umbraco 7 you can use **Umbraco.Web.Security.MembershipHelper** class.
An instance of it is accessible via **Members** property in views inheriting from:

- `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage`
- `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage`
- `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<T>`

also in controllers inheriting from:

- `Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController`
- `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController`

**to login member programmatically:** `Members.Login("username", "password");`
**to pull member via email:** `Members.GetByEmail("email"); // returns IPublishedContent`

Complete public interface of `Umbraco.Web.Security.MembershipHelper` class:

```
  /// <summary> A helper class for handling Members </summary>
  public class MembershipHelper
  {
    public MembershipHelper(ApplicationContext applicationContext, HttpContextBase httpContext);
    public MembershipHelper(UmbracoContext umbracoContext);

    /// <summary> Returns true if the current membership provider is the Umbraco built-in one. </summary>
    public bool IsUmbracoMembershipProviderActive();

    /// <summary> Updates the currently logged in members profile </summary>
    /// <returns> The updated MembershipUser object </returns>
    public Attempt<MembershipUser> UpdateMemberProfile(ProfileModel model);

    /// <summary> Registers a new member </summary>
    /// <param name="model"/><param name="status"/>
    /// <param name="logMemberIn">true to log the member in upon successful registration </param>
    public MembershipUser RegisterMember(RegisterModel model, out MembershipCreateStatus status, bool logMemberIn = true);

    /// A helper method to perform the validation and logging in of a member - this is simply wrapping standard membership provider and asp.net forms auth logic.
    public bool Login(string username, string password);

    /// <summary> Logs out the current member </summary>
    public void Logout();

    public IPublishedContent GetByProviderKey(object key);
    public IPublishedContent GetById(int memberId);
    public IPublishedContent GetByUsername(string username);
    public IPublishedContent GetByEmail(string email);

    /// <summary> Returns the currently logged in member as IPublishedContent </summary>
    public IPublishedContent GetCurrentMember();

    /// <summary> Returns the currently logged in member id, -1 if they are not logged in </summary>
    public int GetCurrentMemberId();

    /// Creates a new profile model filled in with the current members details if they are logged in which allows for editing
    ///             profile properties
    public ProfileModel GetCurrentMemberProfileModel();

    /// Creates a model to use for registering new members with custom member properties
    public RegisterModel CreateRegistrationModel(string memberTypeAlias = null);

    /// Returns the login status model of the currently logged in member, if no member is logged in it returns null;
    public LoginStatusModel GetCurrentLoginStatus();

    /// <summary> Check if a member is logged in </summary>
    public bool IsLoggedIn();

    /// Returns true or false if the currently logged in member is authorized based on the parameters provided
    public bool IsMemberAuthorized(bool allowAll = false, IEnumerable<string> allowTypes = null, IEnumerable<string> allowGroups = null, IEnumerable<int> allowMembers = null);

    /// Changes password for a member/user given the membership provider and the password change model
    public Attempt<PasswordChangedModel> ChangePassword(string username, ChangingPasswordModel passwordModel, string membershipProviderName);
    public Attempt<PasswordChangedModel> ChangePassword(string username, ChangingPasswordModel passwordModel, MembershipProvider membershipProvider);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I found a workaround a while back but this was very useful and I am sure quiet a few people will find it useful